# Lightning Application - how to make it show up with the Salesforce Header and Nav?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have this simple Salesforce application:

It works except it shows up completely by itself in its own window. I want it to appear as a page inside of Salesforce so I can see the Salesforce header and navigation. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you also share the code? Have you extended the application to use force:slds?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will be possible. Why don't you create a lightning component instead of app and then create a tab with that component?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by embedding the App inside a Visualforce Page. Not ideal, but it worked. Thanks for the help.